# Footer line isn't where it's supposed to be in review stats and history

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review

This is how the [stats for the low quality posts queue](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review-beta/low-quality-posts/stats) looks like:

[image]

Same thing happens in the history tab, for example check out the [first posts history](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review-beta/first-posts/history).

Just in case this is browser specific, I'm on Chrome 22.0.1229.79 m (latest stable), on Win7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build.

Comment: Hi, this appears fixed everywhere on Chrome, but it's still broken on Firefox 11.0 in the main [review page](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review/), where the footer line overlaps with the last queue, Suggested Edits. Do you want me to post a separate Meta question about it?

Comment: Jin, what @RocMartí reports was just posted as a [separate bug report](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/footer-line-floats-up-too-high-in-the-main-review-page).