# Footer line floats up too high in the main review page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review

I'm seeing this on Chromium 22 (Windows & Linux) & Firefox 15 (Windows):

> [image]

The footer line is a bit in the way. Tried the usual clearing of caches/hard refresh but that doesn't seem to help.

<sub>Related: [Footer line isn't where it's supposed to be in review stats and history](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4064/footer-line-isnt-where-its-supposed-to-be-in-review-stats-and-history) - but that's not on the same page.</sub>

It's also broke in Chrome 22, but only on the review page, not the stats:

[image]

---

Additional info – this link:

```
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review/
           this thing here looks important ^
```

which is what "review" in the header links to, leads me to a page with the footer misplaced as in the screenshots above.

**But**, this one:

```
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review
```

which is what the "Review" in the in-page header (to the left of the stats and buttons in the review pages themselves) links to, leads me to a page with the footer *where it's supposed to be*.

Hoping this could help debugging the issue.

Comment: I don't see this in Chrome, but it was [reported again](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/4064/footer-line-isnt-where-its-supposed-to-be-in-review-stats-and-history#comment11558_4066) for Firefox (good thing you posted this as a bug report though, comments aren't that visible and may go unnoticed).

Comment: Oh, hadn't seen those comments. Might be very version-sensitive, I created this question yesterday, but I couldn't reproduce on a Win7 VM, so I actually waited to have a "real" Windows machine to check on (Vista), and it does repro here, Chrome v2.0.1229.79m. (Oh and it doesn't actually interfere with site functions, so it's really minor.)

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I'm not seeing it on Win7/IE9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed now. Programmers (along with [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) and [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)) tends to require more one-off, site-specific CSS fixes than other sites. The bug was: without the trailing forward slash in the url, we weren't applying the `review-page` class to `<body>` element, so certain styles weren't being applied.