# Line in UI goes under review tasks

Tags: bug, design, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Footer line floats up too high in the main review page](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/footer-line-floats-up-too-high-in-the-main-review-page)

See the screenshot below. I don't know whether this is because I only have 249 rep, but it's there, all right.

[image: Screenshot]

<sub>Note: I am currently behind a firewall that blocks Imgur so I can't guarantee the screenshot looks OK for a viewer. All I know is that it has been added to the page successfully. I'll fix it if needed when I can.</sub>

Edit: Just realized this is a dupe of [Footer line floats up too high in the main review page](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/footer-line-floats-up-too-high-in-the-main-review-page). Can someone close it?