# Image covers the review page

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Footer line floats up too high in the main review page](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/footer-line-floats-up-too-high-in-the-main-review-page)

Looking the [review page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/), I notice the list of the review queue is covered by the image I normally see at the bottom of other pages.

[image: screenshot]

It seems to happen just on that page, while on the front page that image appears in the footer.

[image: screenshot]

I inspected the page using Safari 6 Web Inspector, but I didn't see any reference to that image, if not in the .header `<div>`.